# What is the name of this plant has dazzling look like leaves?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I am living in India. My neighbours are growing this plant and they even don't know what it was, but its leaves really dazzled me.

[image]

Comment: Google Image search has an option to upload a photo to it and it will show you matches. You could find these plant names that way too. Not just by asking on this forum.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is ***Jatropha podagrica*** also known as *Buddha Belly*.

It comes under succulent plants.

[image]

Source: *[flowersofindia.net](http://www.flowersofindia.net)*